# Converting HSV to RGB in Python

Tags: python, rgb, hsv

```
    pt = Point(x,y) 
    h=angle
    s=length
    RGB=colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, s, 0)
    print (RGB)
    pt.setFill(color_rgb(RGB))
    pt.draw(win)
```

I get error message: "color_rgb() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'g' and 'b'" but if I print RGB I get: "(-0.0, -0.0, 0)", so there is three.

I made corrections below:

```
    pt = Point(x,y) 
    h=angle
    s=length
    print (h,s)
    RGB=colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, s, h + s)
    pt.setFill(color_rgb(*RGB))
    pt.draw(win)
```

But now I get error message:

File "D:\Python\graphics.py", line 962, in color_rgb
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % (r,g,b)
TypeError: %x format: an integer is required, not float

Comment: You need to "unpack" the tuple in three elements.

Comment: Ok, thanks! :) But sorry :( Ihave to ask, how I do it?

Answer (score 1):

`RGB` is here a 3-tuple, but you can not pass this tuple to `color_rgb`: this method requires three parameters. You can however *unpack* the tuple in three parameters, with for example the asterisk (`*`) in front:

```
pt.setFill(color_rgb(*RGB))
```

or you can first unpack the tuple in three variables:

```
r, g, b = RGB
pt.setFill(color_rgb(r, g, b))
```

Note however that if the `v` parameter is set to `0`, this will *always* return `(0, 0, 0)` since HSV is basically a cone, and the `v` parameter determines the distance from the "top" to the "surface", as is demonstrated on the [Wikipedia image [wiki]](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:HSV_color_solid_cone.png) below:

[image]

So with `v=0`, this will always result in *black*, regardless of the value for the `h`ue and `s`aturation.